# What is the purpose of using {} [()] in the below for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

This for loop runs without any error, but I couldn't figure out what is the purpose of {} [()].

```
a = [(0, 'Hello'), (1, 'World')]
for {} [()], x in a:
    print (x)
```

The output it produces -

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: `for _, x in a:` does the same thing.  So does `for {():(())} [(())], x in a:`  I'm also not sure what's happening here, but I think every iteration of the for loop tries to destructure the incoming object `(0, 'Hello')` into `{} [()], x`, which means it destructures `Hello` into `x` and `0` into `{} [()]`.

Comment: The first one makes sense since '_' is a valid variable name.  But this one, I couldn't understand how this 0 is getting mapped to {} [()] without any error.

Comment: I think I mostly figured it out: `{} [()]` behaves identically to `{}[()]` (no space).  So really it is unpacking `0` into `{}[()]` (the value of an empty dictionary corresponding to the key of empty tuple?)

Comment: This appears copied from a tweet from dabeaz: https://twitter.com/dabeaz/status/1199367834691932160

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have to be a valid name, just a valid assignment target. So it creates a dictionary, `{}` then assigns 0 (on the first iteration) to the key that is an empty tuple. This is just stupid, there is no purpose. The dicts created are immediately discarded.

So try:

```
{}[()] = 0
```

Comment: It's unfortunately out-of-context. [This](https://twitter.com/dabeaz/status/1199367834691932160) link was posted in the python chat room yesterday and will also have been seen by others on Twitter. It was a conversation-starter and a few of us learned some stuff on the way, but I agree it doesn't merit being a question (in this form).

Answer (score 1):

The only real purpose is to take up space in order to throw away the first tuple element, just like _ would.

As to why it's valid python, it translates to:

1. take an empty dict **{}**
2. create a key in it mapped to empty tuple **()**
3. assign the first tuple item in each element in **a** to it
4. after the assignment it is gone right away since it is not bound to a name

() can be a dict key because it is hashable, for example:

```
In [1]: {():1}[()]
Out[1]: 1
```

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing it out, I have corrected that sentence